# rsync 3.2.3 Transfer a globbed subset of files from a single source directory and ignore the rest

Tags: rsync

Variations on this question are everywhere and I have tried many suggested solutions. Yet I cannot grasp what it is that I am missing in the following `rsync` command:

This sends everything in the source directory, which I do not want:

```
    echo "$HP3000_SRC"  "$HP0000_DST_HOST":"$HP3000_DST_DIR"
    /tmp/hp3000 192.168.216.107:/usr/local/www/apache24/data/hll_DaV/upload/Other_Scans

rsync --dry-run -avz -ogt --include="./" --include="*pdf-Q*"  --rsh='ssh -p22' "$HP3000_SRC"  "$HP0000_DST_HOST":"$HP3000_DST_DIR" 
!!Warning!! -   Any deliberate attempt to access this resource without 
                legitimate authorization is a criminal offence
                (R.S.C. 1985, c. C-46 - Section 342.1).
sending incremental file list
hp3000/
hp3000/HP3000-2021-04-23T23:27:16-04:00.pdf
hp3000/HP3000-2021-04-23T23:27:18-04:00.pdf
hp3000/HP3000-2021-04-23T23:27:18-04:00.pdf-QZARDBD
hp3000/HP3000-2021-04-23T23:27:19-04:00.pdf
hp3000/HP3000-2021-04-23T23:27:21-04:00.pdf
hp3000/HP3000-2021-04-23T23:27:21-04:00.pdf-QZCCB3R
hp3000/HP3000-2021-04-23T23:27:24-04:00.pdf
hp3000/HP3000-2021-04-23T23:27:24-04:00.pdf-QZCCMWR
hp3000/HP3000-2021-04-24T05:52:33-04:00.pdf
hp3000/HP3000-2021-04-24T05:52:33-04:00.pdf-QZARBDW
hp3000/HP3000-2021-04-24T05:52:34-04:00.pdf
hp3000/HP3000-2021-04-24T05:52:34-04:00.pdf-QZARDBJ
hp3000/HP3000-2021-04-24T05:52:35-04:00.pdf
hp3000/HP3000-2021-04-24T05:52:35-04:00.pdf-QZCCUBT
hp3000/HP3000-2021-04-24T05:52:36-04:00.pdf
hp3000/HP3000-2021-04-24T05:52:36-04:00.pdf-QZGLRQB
hp3000/HP3000-2021-04-25T00:39:49-04:00.pdf
hp3000/HP3000-2021-04-25T00:39:49-04:00.pdf-QZAPATB
hp3000/HP3000-REPORTS.txt

sent 811 bytes  received 77 bytes  592.00 bytes/sec
total size is 701,038  speedup is 789.46 (DRY RUN)
```

While this sends nothing at all:

```
rsync --dry-run -avz -ogt --include="./" --include="*pdf-Q*" --exclude="*"  --rsh='ssh -p22' "$HP3000_SRC"  "$HP0000_DST_HOST":"$HP3000_DST_DIR" !!Warning!! -  Any deliberate attempt to access this resource without 
                legitimate authorization is a criminal offence
                (R.S.C. 1985, c. C-46 - Section 342.1).
sending incremental file list

sent 18 bytes  received 12 bytes  20.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

All I want transferred are the files containing "`pdf-Q`".  What invocation of `rsync` accomplishes this; and why does the `--exclude` override the `--include`?

Comment: How about `--include '**pdf-Q*' --exclude '*'` (in that order)?

Comment: Double star?  I will check.

Comment: Did not work: 

`rsync --dry-run -avz --include "**pdf-Q*" --exclude "*" /tmp/hp3000/send/ 192.168.216.107:/usr/local/www/apache24/data/hll_DaV/upload/Other_Scans/hp3000
!!Warning!! - Any deliberate attempt to access this resource without 
                legitimate authorization is a criminal offence
                (R.S.C. 1985, c. C-46 - Section 342.1).
sending incremental file list
./

sent 386 bytes  received 19 bytes  810.00 bytes/sec
total size is 332,303  speedup is 820.50 (DRY RUN)`

Comment: Canniot format in comments I see.  Anyway this is one of the files I wished to transfer:  `/tmp/hp3000/send/HP3000-2021-04-25T00:39:49-04:00.pdf-QZAPATB`.  As you can see, it is in the right place and meets the include criteria.

Comment: Right, and it works fine for me: https://bpa.st/VLVA

Comment: Not for me.  I do not know if FreeBSD version of `rsync` behaves differently from other implementations but I cannot get it to send only included files.

Comment: Hmm, what shell did you use? Was it bash? I wonder if it's something to do with the quoting...

Comment: You may have the answer.  I cannot try your suggestion at the moment.  However, the shell is bash so perhaps I should escape the `*` character with `'` marks instead of `"`.

Comment: I was testing with bash as well though. `"` worked fine.

Comment: I think that I must have omitted the `--exclude=*` option in my earliest trials.  I cannot see why the later ones with the `--exclude=*` did not work but I believe that  started out on the wrong foot. In any case, copying a `rsync` command from `.bash_history` and re-running it now works.  I do not know what it was I was doing wrong or what changed in the interim, but I cannot duplicate the error.

Comment: @JamesB.Byrne did my answer work for you? If so please ✔ accept it. If not, what've I missed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Include and exclude options apply from left to right: for any given file or directory the first one that matches is the one that's applied.

Looking at your command

> ```
> rsync --dry-run -avz -ogt --include="./" --include="*pdf-Q*"  --rsh='ssh -p22' "$HP3000_SRC"  "$HP0000_DST_HOST":"$HP3000_DST_DIR"
> ```

You would match the topmost directory (which already happens, so this is a no-op), then include anything with `pdf-Q` in the file name. There are no exclusions so nothing is excluded.

Try this instead (you don't need `-ogt` because these options are already implied by `-a`).

```
rsync --dry-run -avz --include='**/' --include='*pdf-Q*' --exclude '*' --prune-empty-dirs --rsh='ssh -q' "$HP3000_SRC"  "$HP0000_DST_HOST":"$HP3000_DST_DIR"
```